# ebay OAuth 2.0 library Cannot Resolve method initialize()

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, oauth-2.0, ebay-sdk

i wanted to write a bit for Android ebay client.

but im struggeling with the first probleme.
first i start a new Java Android Project with IntelliJ

I want to use this Library [ebay-oauth-android-client](https://github.com/eBay/ebay-oauth-android-client)

like described on Git:

> Obtaining Library
>
> This library is distributed via maven central repository. To use this
>   library, include the below as dependency in your project

```
 dependencies {
     compile 'com.ebay.auth:ebay-oauth-android-client:1.0.1'
 }
```

i put this snippet in my Gradle.build and replace compile with implementation since compile is depricated.

so far so good. gradle import this library.

but the next step not working for me:

> Application Setup
>    Before performing OAuth, the library should be initialized with details about your application from  eBay developer portal. The library uses
>
> Client ID. For details see Getting your OAuth credentials
>   Redirect Uri. for details see Getting your Redirect_Uri
>   Url encoded list of scopes. for details see Specifying OAuth scopes
>   Use these details in ApiSessionConfiguration.initialize() as shown below:

```
 ApiSessionConfiguration.initialize(
                apiEnvironment = ApiEnvironment.PRODUCTION,
                apiConfiguration = ApiConfiguration(
                    <Client ID>,
                    <Redirect Uri>,
                    <space separated scopes>
                )
            )
```

So i try to call initialze:

[my Code with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4Z1R.jpg)

But when i try that the Compiler tells me that:

```
cannot find symbol method initialize(<null>)
```

When i Jump to the Class Declaration of ApiSessionConfiguration is written that:

```
// IntelliJ API Decompiler stub source generated from a class file
// Implementation of methods is not available

package com.ebay.api.client.auth.oauth2.model

public final class ApiSessionConfiguration private constructor() {
    public companion object {
        private final val instance: com.ebay.api.client.auth.oauth2.model.ApiSessionConfiguration /* compiled code */

        public final fun getInstance(): com.ebay.api.client.auth.oauth2.model.ApiSessionConfiguration { /* compiled code */ }

        public final fun initialize(apiEnvironment: com.ebay.api.client.auth.oauth2.model.ApiEnvironment, apiConfiguration: com.ebay.api.client.auth.oauth2.model.ApiConfiguration): com.ebay.api.client.auth.oauth2.model.ApiSessionConfiguration { /* compiled code */ }
    }

    public final var apiConfiguration: com.ebay.api.client.auth.oauth2.model.ApiConfiguration? /* compiled code */

    public final var apiEnvironment: com.ebay.api.client.auth.oauth2.model.ApiEnvironment? /* compiled code */
}
```

i dont really understand what im doing wrong. in the sample file on Git ApiSessionConfiguration.initalize() is called without any errors.

i already tried to Invalidate Cache, Clean Build, and start over again.
when i try to import the library from Project Structure Librarys New from Maven repo it says:
no files were downloaded...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't it can resolve `initialize` method with single argument?
Did you tried `initialize` method with two arguments?

Their sample app takes 2 arguments:
https://github.com/eBay/ebay-oauth-android-client/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/ebay/api/client/auth/MainActivity.kt#L37-L44

Updated:
But to access to Kotlin companion object function from java you need to call `ApiSessionConfiguration.Companion.initialize` method

Comment: I found out the Library was written in Kotlin also the sample app. When i start a new Project in Kotlin its working. Bit i thought i can use Kotlin Syntax in Java?

Comment: Ah yes i was blind because of the sample. Now i can call it. Thank you!